# Придаточные изъяснительные, пример из Википедии

Tags: грамматика

На [странице в Википедии о придаточных предложениях](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8A%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5) в разделе: "придаточное изъяснительное" указан пример:
"Деревня, где скучал Евгений, была прелестный уголок".

Если  я верно понимаю, данный пример относится к *придаточному определительному*, т. к. отвечает на вопрос "какая?": [деревня]. Деревня *какая?* (где скучал Евгений).
[Деревня, (где скучал Евгений), была прелестный уголок]

В предыдущем разделе: "придаточное определительное" имеется похожий пример:
[Дом сгорел дотла]. Дом какой? (Где я родился).
[Дом, ( где я родился), сгорел дотла].

Пример который, как мне кажется, имеет *придаточное изъяснительное*:

В блаженной тишине родилась у меня жгучая мысль о том, что исполнилось мое мечтание и бабка Павловна, торгующая папиросами, умерла. (М. Булгаков)
[В блаженной тишине родилась у меня жгучая мысль о том]. *родилась мысль о чем?*, (что исполнилось мое мечтание и бабка Павловна, торгующая папиросами, умерла). (М. Булгаков)

Вопросы:

1. верно ли я определил, что пример который указан (Деревня, где скучал...) относится к *придаточному определительному?*
2. подходит ли  пример:
   «В блаженной тишине родилась у меня жгучая мысль о том, что исполнилось мое мечтание и бабка Павловна, торгующая папиросами, умерла.» в качестве придаточного изъяснительного ?
3. какая часть из "нового" примера относится к придаточному предложению:

[В блаженной тишине родилась у меня жгучая мысль о том]. *родилась мысль о чем?*, (что исполнилось мое мечтание и бабка Павловна, торгующая папиросами, умерла).
т.е "что исполнилось мое мечтание и бабка Павловна, торгующая папиросами, умерла"

или

[В блаженной тишине родилась у меня жгучая мысль о том]. *родилась мысль о чем?*, (что исполнилось мое мечтание) и бабка Павловна, торгующая папиросами, умерла].
То есть "что исполнилось мое мечтание".

Comment: В Вики этого предложения под темой "Придаточные изъяснительные" уже нет. Убрали?

Answer (score 1):

1. СПП с придаточными **определительными**:

*Деревня (какая?), **где скучал Евгений**, была прелестный уголок.*

*Дом (какой?), **где я родился**, сгорел дотла.*

Сравнить: *Деревня, **в которой** скучал Евгений, была прелестный уголок.*

Опорные (определяемые) существительные: ***деревня, дом.***

Условно можно сравнить **обстоятельственными** определениями в простом предложении (***в которой? где?***).

2. ***СПП*** с однородными придаточными **изъяснительными**, союз ***И***, запятая не ставится:

***В блаженной тишине родилась у меня жгучая мысль о том**, что исполнилось мое мечтание **и** бабка Павловна, торгующая папиросами, умерла.*

Опорное существительное ***мысль*** (мысли,предположения, мнения).

Comment: Эта тема https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478899/Трудное-предложение-грамматика-и-знаки-препинания

Answer (score 0):

**1.**
Предложение: ‟где скучал Евгений” — является придаточным места.
**2.**
Да, подходит. Только это два изъяснительных придаточных.

**3.**
Предложения: ‟что исполнилось мое мечтание” и ‟бабка Павловна, торгующая папиросами, умерла” — являются сложносочиненными по отношению друг к другу и придаточными по отношению к предложению: ‟в блаженной тишине родилась у меня жгучая мысль о том”.

Comment: Поправил, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: _Jim Korbett: Предложение: ‟где скучал Евгений” — является придаточным места._ === **Нет!** _Деревня (**какая?**)…_  На такой вопрос отвечают придаточные **определительные**.

Comment: А почему вопрос ‟какая”? Почему не ‟где”? Лол!